# MongoDB search error

Tags: mongodb

I use mongoDB (version 3.0.2) for my application and if I will search for a User named "Hannes" than I get the following error above. 
db.User.find() works without any problems.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks a lot!

```
db.User.find({$text:{$search:'Hannes'}})


Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=apoSoftDatabase.User limit=0 skip=0\nTree: TEXT : query=Hannes, language=, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query",
    "code" : 17007
}
```

[**EDIT**]
This is my document structure:

```
db.User.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("5589929b887dc1fdb501cdbf"), "_class" : "com.smartinnotec.aposoft.dao.domain.User", "title" : "", "firstname" : "Claudia", "surname" : "Amreiter", "birthdate" : ISODate("1989-06-02T03:43:43.124Z"), "sex" : "FEMALE", "telephone" : "0664 / 342233223", "email" : "claudia.amreiter@aon.de", "username" : "claudia", "password" : "claudiapw", "address" : { "_id" : null, "street" : "strasse 21a", "postalCode" : 58441, "region" : "village", "country" : "Germany" }})
```

Comment: can you post your sample document structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "error" is because uou don't have a ["text" index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) on your collection and you need one to use the [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator in queries.

### Create a text index

Your document may have fields like:

```js
{
    "a": "sam",
    "b": "wise"
}
```

You can then create a "text index" over all or just a single field with something like:

```js
db.collection.createIndex({ "a": "text", "b": "text" })
```

Then you can query with:

```js
db.collection.find({ "$text": { "$search": "sam wise" } })
```

Or any other valid combination without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the field name of your collection, however you can try this:

Try db.User.find({**[field name]**:'Hannes'})

Comment: Thanks for the response: with your command I get: db.User.find({[field firstname]:'Hannes'}) 
2015-07-13T15:13:55.996+0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token [